# Get Nested value from JSON response with python

Tags: json, python-3.6

This is my JSON response

```
{

    "items": [
        {
            "consult": {
                "id": "1",
                "active": "1",
                "created_at": "1366375054",
                "modified_at": "1375400022",
                "code": "300001",
                "date": "1366375054",
                "animal_id": "1",
                "vet_id": "0",
                "referring_vet_contact_id": "",
                "referring_clinic_id": "",
                "description": "Vaccination",
                "presenting_problem_link_list": [],
                "ownership_id": "1"
            }
        },

    ],
    "messages": []
}
```

I need to extract id and date from the response, I tried with following python code but not getting what I need:

```
responseData = response.json()
resp_dict = json.loads(responseData)
print(resp_dict['items'][0])['id'])
print(resp_dict['items'][0])['date'])
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the 'consult' key.

`resp_dict['items'][0]['consult']['id']`

Comment: Hi @Adeom, Thanks for your quick response.Will try and update you soon.

Comment: I am getting error TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict' from this line resp_dict = json.loads(responseData). this is my code.                      `response = requests.get("https://api)                                               
    responseData = response.json()
    resp_dict = json.loads(responseData)
    print(resp_dict['items'][0]['consult']['id'])`

Comment: Hi  Working now using following code `responseData = response.text#.json()
                resp_dict = json.loads(responseData)
                print(resp_dict['items'][0]['consult']['id'] + "\n")
                print(resp_dict['items'][0]['consult']['date'])`              How can i get the last consult id and date ?  Thanks

Comment: When indexing list in python, negative index will point from the end of the list (starting with `-1` as the last element). So simply use `-1` index for last entry in list `resp_dict['items'][-1]['consult']['id']`

Comment: Also, as you are using requests libarary, you don't have to call `json.loads(response.text)`, this is same as calling `response.json()`.